# Mapping not working in knockout with the button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Mapping not working in knockout with the button click,

I have used mapping in knockout, while changing input text value when clicking button not changed properly. 
Need to change value for *name input text* after click *load user data* button

Here my code,

```
    <div class='sample'>
    <p>Load: <input type="button" value="Load User Data" data-bind="click: loadUserData" /></p>
    <p>Name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p>
    <p>Save: <input type="button" value="Save User Data" data-bind="click: saveUserData" /></p>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = {};
        viewModel.firstName = 'Knockout JS';
        viewModel.loadUserData = function () {
            $.getJSON("/data.json", function (data) {
                // update the data in existing ViewModel.
                viewModel.firstName = data.name;
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);

            });
        };
        viewModel.saveUserData = function () {
            // Convert the viewModel into JSON.
            var data_to_send = { userData: ko.toJSON(viewModel) };
            // Send that JOSN data to server.
            $.post("WebService.asmx/updateData", data_to_send, function (data) {
                alert("Your data has been posted to the server!");
            });
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

Did i anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it update the UI, you need to make the firstName `observable`.

Then when you want to modify an observable value, you need to treat that as a function and pass the new value as an argument like this `firstName('newValue')`

See the link [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) to get more information and a sample below:

```js
var masterVM = (function () {
  var self = this;      
  self.firstName = ko.observable("Knockout JS");
  self.loadUserData = function() {
    var currentName = self.firstName();
    self.firstName(currentName + "Updated");
  }
})();

ko.applyBindings(masterVM);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>Load: <input type="button" value="Load User Data" data-bind="click: loadUserData" /></p>
<p>Name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p>
```